# jQuery doesn't pick up programmatic element.onchange() calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

**This is more of an educational question rather than a problem to be solved.**

So I've got an `input` which is styled using [Ryan Fait's custom elements plugin](http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/).

```
<input type="checkbox" class="styled" id="no-favourite" />
```

I bound a jQuery `change()` handler:

```
$("#no-favourite").change(function(){
    console.log("changed"); 
});
```

and edited the custom elements plugin's `check` method to include:

```
try{
    element.onchange(); 
}catch(err){
    console.log(err);
}
```

This didn't work. I expected a `console.log` of "changed", and at worst a `console.log` error, although received neither. The jQuery `change` handler gets called when clicking on the associated `label`.

I solved the problem by using:

```
$(element).change();
```

So I am wondering, why does jQuery not pick up a programmatic call to `element.onchange()` ?

Comment: I might be wrong here but `onchange` is a method of an element through which you can bind `onchange` event hadlers but can't trigger event handlers already bound. jQuery must be doing it some how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `element` is a DOM element (if it were a jQuery element it would just blow up), you are attempting to invoke the element's property `onchange`.

When you bind an event handler through jQuery, it does not add any `onchange` properties - these would only exist if you bound the handler inline (in markup) or through native javascript.

Comment: So does jQuery automatically bind the change handler to any associated labels? Or, how does that side of it work?

Comment: @ahren jQuery stores this information in an internal `data` object

Comment: @ahren - Internally, jQuery binds event handlers with `addEventListener` or `attachEvent` (depending on the browser) rather than `onchange` or `onclick` or whatever. I haven't looked at the source for a while, but I assume it only binds each event once per element with a hook into its own code that then invokes the callbacks _you_ bind in the correct order.

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery` stores events bound using their api in a special `data` container inside each of the object, so you can't really call it using `on*` native methods (which can only be set natively using `.onchange = function()` or inline `onchange=`).

If you fire up your console (chrome), and type `$.event`, you'll see jQuery internal representation of events, and "default" events are stored in `$.event.global`, and it's managed internally.

Search for `jQuery.event.global[ type ]` at http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.js

```
    if ( (!elem || jQuery.event.customEvent[ type ]) && !jQuery.event.global[ type ] ) {
        // No jQuery handlers for this event type, and it can't have inline handlers
        return;
    }

    // Caller can pass in an Event, Object, or just an event type string
    event = typeof event === "object" ?
        // jQuery.Event object
        event[ jQuery.expando ] ? event :
        // Object literal
        new jQuery.Event( type, event ) :
        // Just the event type (string)
        new jQuery.Event( type );
```